# Adding entry to Firefox cache from an XPCOM component

Tags: firefox, caching, xpcom, gecko

The nsICacheSession has a method openCacheEntry() which returns an existing cache entry. Is there a method such as createCacheEntry() that will create a cache entry. I want to create an XPCOM object that will read files from disk and write them to Firefox cache.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated in MDC [nsICache interface reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICache) opening an entry with **ACCESS_WRITE** will create the entry if it doesn't already exist (if it already exists, the entry will be doomed so you can replace it with a new one).

Perhaps a little too late for the original poster, but this can be useful for other people out there.